# Is there a `flutter doctor doctor`?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

So I ran `flutter doctor` and it says that Android studio is missing.

I install Android Studio, run `flutter doctor` again, but it doesn't detect android studio and still displays the same message.

Why is `flutter doctor` not detecting it?

Is there a tool to fix the tool that fixes flutter? Like `flutter doctor doctor` for example?

Comment: Did you restart the computer? Can you include full  out-put of `flutter doctor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed Android Studio properly by following the steps listed in this [doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#install-android-studio), then just try to restart your Terminal or PC.
If it doesn't show after this, then there is no need to worry as still, you should be able to build and debug Flutter Android apps without the Android Studio being detected.

Answer (score 2):

try this: `flutter doctor -vv`

```
-v, --verbose               Noisy logging, including all shell commands
                            executed.
                            If used with "--help", shows hidden options. If used
                            with "flutter doctor", shows additional diagnostic
                            information. (Use "-vv" to force verbose logging in
                            those cases.)
```

Answer (score 0):

After installing `AndroidStudio` install `tools` and `plugins`, if you still face any issue, do a restart.

Also, you can follow [install guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install)

Does it solve in your case?

Answer (score 0):

After installing Android Studio, you have to install Flutter SDK and add it to the path in Windows environment variables, and also before all this, it is better to install JDK8 (not 11 not 16 just 8).

Once you have done all that I said, you can restart your terminal or CMD in windows and now run the `flutter doctor`

and for details on that you should run `flutter doctor -v`

Link for download flutter SDK : https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install

Link for download JDK 8 : https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html